# Cannot get jwt token from cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, mern

I am using mern stack to make one website. I am using jwt and trying to store them in cookies. I invoked the res.cookie function with parameters(you can find the code below). But somehow I cannot find the cookie in the browser.
[no cookie found(top portion) whereas name of cookie(=jwt) found in network tab in inspect. Please look at this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zyD50.jpg)

But when I check the network tab in the inspect, there is a cookie present in Set-cookie.

Assuming that the cookie has been stored, I try to access the jwt token, but in vain.

I am providing the code below.

This is my file where all the routes are written.

```
const express = require ("express")
const Resident = require("../models/residentModels");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
// const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/register", async (req, res) =\> {
try {
const resident = new Resident(req.body);

        console.log(req.body);
    
        // password hash 
        // middleware
        const token = await resident.generateAuthToken();
    
        console.log("token: " + token);
    
        res.cookie("jwt", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: new Date (Date.now() + 12342)
        })
        // console.log(cookie);
    
        const newResident = await resident.save();
    
        console.log("hehe" + newResident);
        // console.log(newResident._id);
        // console.log(newResident._id.toString());
    
        res.status(200).send("Record Added Successfully");
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(200).send("Record Creation Unsuccessfull");
    }

})

router.post("/login", async (req, res) =\> {
try {
let blockNumber = req.body.blockNumber;
let flatNumber = req.body.flatNumber;
let password = req.body.password;

        console.log(blockNumber)
        console.log(flatNumber)
        console.log(password)
    
        const response = await Resident.findOne({blockNumber: blockNumber, flatNumber:flatNumber});
    
        console.log(response);
    
        const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, response.password);
    
        console.log("isMatch: " + isMatch);
    
        const token = await response.generateAuthToken();
        console.log("token part: " + token);
    
        let cookie = res.cookie("jwt", token, {
            httpOnly: true,
            expires: new Date (Date.now() + 10000)
        })
        // console.log(cookie)
    
        // console.log(`this is the cookie awesome !! + ${req.cookies.jwt}`);
        let jwtToken = req.cookies;
        console.log("req.cookies.jwt: " + jwtToken);
    
        if(isMatch){
            res.status(200).send("Successful Login");
        }
        else{
            res.status(200).send("Invalid Login Details");
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(200).send("Invalid Login Details");
    }

});

module.exports = router;
```

This is my index.js file :

```
const express = require("express");
require('./db/conn');
const Resident = require("./routes/residentRoutes");
var cors = require("cors");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(Resident);
app.use(cookieParser());

const port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");

const securePassword = async (password) =\> {
const passwordHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);
console.log(passwordHash);

    const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, passwordHash)
    console.log(passwordMatch);

}

securePassword("thapa@123");

const createToken = async () =\> {
const token = await jwt.sign({\_id: "63e677a57d45b06c8557441a"}, "thisisnotformyresumebutmyideology!!!",{
expiresIn: "20 seconds"
})
console.log(token);

    const userVerify = await jwt.verify(token, "thisisnotformyresumebutmyideology!!!");
    console.log(userVerify); // returns an object

}

createToken();

app.listen(port, () =\> {
console.log(`connection successful at port ${port}`);
})
```

In the file where all the routes are written, the variable jwtToken returns "undefined".
As a result, it is evident that the cookie was not stored.

So now the question arises how do I store the cookies and where am I doing wrong?

P.S.: I am using React.js in the frontend.

My Login.jsx file looks like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React from 'react'
import { NavLink, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'

const Login = () => {

  let navigate = useNavigate();

  const loginButton = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    // console.log(event.target[0].value); // block number

    let blockNumber = event.target[0].value;
    let flatNumber = event.target[1].value;
    let password = event.target[2].value;

    const response = await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login', {
      blockNumber: blockNumber,
      flatNumber: flatNumber,
      password: password
    })

    // console.log("response :" + response.data);
    console.log(response);

    if(response.status === 200){
      navigate("/dashboard");
    }
    else{
      alert("Invalid Login Details");
    }
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h1> Login </h1>
      <form onSubmit={loginButton}>
        <input type="number" placeholder='Block Number *' />
        <input type="number" placeholder='Flat Number *' />
        <input type="password" placeholder='Password *' />

        <button type="submit">Login</button>
        <NavLink to='/register'>or Click to Register</NavLink>
      </form>
    </>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Comment: PS: I want the jwt token to be created and stored in cookies when I am at /login route

Answer (score 0):

In your index.js file

Swap these two from:

```
app.use(Resident);
app.use(cookieParser());
```

to:

```
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(Resident);
```

You need to parse the request first before accessing the routes

The sequence matter how you place your code

Comment: no. not working :(

Answer (score 0):

can you see the cookies in the application tab of browser developer tools?
If you can, are you using axios? If so, it might be because of that, you need to add `withCredentials`: true in the axios constructor.

```
axios("http://someurl", {
  method: "post",
  data: someJsonData,
  withCredentials: true
})
```